# Python: no change in a pandas dataframe column when using apply function

Tags: python, pandas, apply

As a reproducible example, I created the following dataframe:

```
dictionary = {'Metropolitan area': ['New York City','New York City','Los Angeles', 'Los Angeles'],
              'Population (2016 est.)[8]': [20153634, 20153634, 13310447, 13310447],
              'NBA':['Knicks',' ',' ', 'Clippers']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
```

to substitute any space present in `df['NBA']` by 'None' I created the following function:

```
def transform(x):
if len(x)<2:
    return None
else:
    return x
```

which I apply over `df['NBA']` using `.apply` method:

```
df['NBA'].apply(transform)
```

After doing this, I get the following output, which seems to have been succesful:

```
> 0           Knicks
1    Missing Value
2    Missing Value
3         Clippers
Name: NBA, dtype: object
```

But, here the problem, when I call for `df`, `df['NBA']` is not transformed, and I get that column as it was from the beginning, and the spaces are still present and not replaced by None:

```
    Metropolitan area   Population (2016 est.)[8]   NBA
0   New York City            20153634              Knicks
1   New York City            20153634   
2   Los Angeles              13310447   
3   Los Angeles              13310447              Clippers
```

What am I doing wrong? am I misunderstunding the `.apply` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `df['NBA'].apply(transform)` on its own will do the operation but not save it to the original DataFrame in the memory.

so you just have to save the new column:

```
df['NBA'] = df['NBA'].apply(transform)
```

and the resulting DataFrame should be:

```
Metropolitan area  Population (2016 est.)[8]       NBA
0     New York City                   20153634    Knicks
1     New York City                   20153634      None
2       Los Angeles                   13310447      None
3       Los Angeles                   13310447  Clippers
```

Comment: Oh, sorry @Bill the Lizard, I did not see that you posted the answer while I was writing.

Comment: No worries. I can't tell you how many times I've done the same thing. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assign the results of `apply` back to the column.

```
df['NBA'] = df['NBA'].apply(transform)
```